# PHPUnitCode Coverage readonly classes

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage

I have a project with Laravel 9, phpunit/php-code-coverage: "^9.2" and phpunit/phpunit: "^9.3.3".

I can run individual tests and everything works correctly, but if I try to generate a report in HTML, phpunit throws the following error: `Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... syntax error, unexpected token "readonly", expecting "abstract" or "final" or "class".`

I used to use Laravel 8 and had problems with the Final classes, now that I have upgraded to Laravel 9 with PHP 8.2 I seem to have problems with the Readonly classes.

Does anyone know how I can fix this and generate an HTML report like before?

I have used the library: `https://github.com/zoltanka/bypass-readonly` but it does not work.